# log return calculation from matrix

Tags: r, logging, return

when I have a dataframe named "Historical_Stock_Prices_R" like this

```
Date1       MSFT    AAPL    GOOGL
25-01-05    21.03   4.87    88.56
26-01-05    21.02   4.89    94.62
27-01-05    21.10   4.91    94.04
28-01-05    21.16   5.00    95.17
```

I use the following formulas to get a lsit of monthly max and monthly mean log return from daily price data file

```
return<- cbind.data.frame(date=Historical_Stock_Prices_R$Date1[2:nrow(Historical_Stock_Prices_R)],apply(Historical_Stock_Prices_R[,2:4],2,function(x) log(x[-1]/x[-length(x)])*100))

    return$Date <- as.Date(return$date,format="%d-%m-%y")


    RMax <- aggregate(return[,-1],
                      by=list(Month=format(return$Date,"%y-%m")),
                      FUN=max)

    RMean <- aggregate(return[,-1],
                      by=list(Month=format(return$Date,"%y-%m")),
                      FUN=mean)
```

But now I have a matrix (not a dataframe) named "df" like this

```
          AAPL.High    ABT.High   ABBV.High   ACN.High    ADBE.High
07-01-02    NA            NA         NA          NA           NA
03-01-07    12.37        24.74       NA          37          41.32
04-01-07    12.28        25.12       NA         37.23         41
05-01-07    12.31         25         NA         36.99         40.9
```

Now how can I calculate same monthly mean and monthly max using similar kind of code?

Comment: if you have a `matrix` make it a dataframe by the code `as.data.frame()`

Comment: @Onyambus ok than how can I put "date" in the first cell?

Comment: What do you mean? it is already the first column. or is it not?

Comment: yes, I mean word "Date" as a heading

Comment: before you put it as a dataframe, just do `colnames(df)[1]="Date"` Then do `data.frame(df)`

Comment: the word "Date" comes in the first column of the data not on the date column

Comment: Do you need to put the word "date" as a heading?? or in the first cell?? Both these are what you wrote.. read your comments

Comment: yes but in the Dataframe or matrix format the date column is not comes as a column. it shows date like a column but considers  "AAPL.High" as a first column

Comment: okay I understand your problem. try and do `cbind(Date=row.names(data.frame(df)),data.frame(df))`

Comment: still not working

Comment: `tibble::rowid_to_column(data.frame(df),"date")`

Comment: Error: 'rowid_to_column' is not an exported object from 'namespace:tibble'

Comment: tibble is a package you need to have . do `library(tibble)`. if not present then you have to download it `install.packages("tibble")`